# Memory management with ORC on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, orc

I have a use-case where I have to simultaneously open and read large number ORC files from single hadoop mapper. Because of ORC's stripe caching, it takes 256Mb per file and my mappers run out of heap-space. While I am aware that I can increase mapper memory to avoid memory issue but is there a better way to do the same in lesser memory. 
Please note that I have to open all such files simultaneously via a single hadoop mapper only and I cannot pre-compact them or distribute them among mappers as shuffling is not an option for me.